# How to Remove article id from Joomla 3.4.3

Tags: joomla-3.4, url

I would like to remove article id's from Joomla 3.4.3 urls; example.com/howto/428-how-to-play-android-games-on-your-pc

I have found following from other threads;

`Replace this:
$advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 0);
With this:
$advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 1);
Step 3
You want to edit your router.php file:
- From: ->where($db->quoteName(‘alias’) . ‘ = ‘ . $db->quote($db->quote($segment)));
- To: ->where($db->quoteName(‘alias’) . ‘ = ‘ . $db->quote($segment));`

My question is; will above steps work on Joomla 3.4.3?
What if Joomla updates in future? Will I need to again edit router.php?
Will it destroy url structure, when i change after Joomla update? 
Will it effect SEO?

I have installed quick-starter of Joomla template and now wants to live site before removing id's from urls. I have created articles in Joomla component as I don't want to go with k2. Can somebody recommend me permanent solution which should not break url structure or effect on SEO/

Comment: The simplest solution is to add to menu - it removes article ID. I think you read it here: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-article-id-from-joomlas-sef-urls - take a backup and test. In j3.5 - its on the roadmap - so will hopefully work then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to play with core files. It can have side-effects (where you are alone to support them) and you will have to patch them with every update.

To customize Urls, it is **highly recommended** to install any SEF-oriented extension from [JED/ Site Management/ Sef](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/site-management/sef).

Comment: Thank You Anibal. One more thing does article ids really effect on SEO? I don't have money right now to purchase extension and extension will also slow down site performance. Should I live website? and leave article ids if it wont effect SEO?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rewrite (i see you are using) and .htaccess rules like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[0-9]/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does this work and still?